# How to create and initialize SAFEARRAY of doubles in C++ to pass to C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, safearray

My C# method needs to be invoked from C++

Originally my C# method takes a parameter of type double[], but when calling from C++ it becomes a SAFEARRAY

In C++ I need to take data from an array of doubles, and populate a SAFEARRAY.  I have not found any sample code to do this.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 27):

Following is the code to create a safearray in C++.

```
#include<oaidl.h>

void CreateSafeArray(SAFEARRAY** saData)        
{
    double data[10]; // some sample data to write into the created safearray
    SAFEARRAYBOUND  Bound;
    Bound.lLbound   = 0;
    Bound.cElements = 10;

    *saData = SafeArrayCreate(VT_R8, 1, &Bound);

    double HUGEP *pdFreq;
    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(*saData, (void HUGEP* FAR*)&pdFreq);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
            // copy sample values from data[] to this safearray
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            *pdFreq++ = data[i];
        }
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(*saData);
    }
}
```

Free the pointer when you are finished like the following code-

```
  SAFEARRAY* saData;
  CreateSafeArray(&saData); // Create the safe array
  // use the safearray
  ...
  ...

  // Call the SafeArrayDestroy to destroy the safearray 
  SafeArrayDestroy(saData);
  saData = NULL; // set the pointer to NULL
```

If you use ATL for C++, then better use CComSafeArray declared in "atlsafe.h". This is wrapper for SAFEARRAY. [CComSafeArray Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomsafearray-class?view=msvc-170)

Comment: This article helped me much. Thanks. But using the function like this left me with an empty saData-Pointer.

Comment: @Teetrinker - saData will be empty after SafeArrayDestroy is called. I have added some comments to the my code.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. But the HUGEP and FAR macros are just noise now when everything is 32 or 64 bit.

Answer (score 8):

Continuing on  @Liton's answer, I want to stress his last sentence, i.e. ATL's `CComSafeArray`. It really can save you a lot of typing. `CComSafeArray` has C++ constructors, destructors, operator overloads including one for [ ] that gives you an read / write reference to any element in the `SAFEARRAY`. In short, you can really focus on your business logic and needn't worry about the `SAFEARRAY` plumbing:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlsafe.h>
// ...

    CComSafeArray<double> arr(10);
    arr[0] = 2.0;
    arr[1] = 3.0;
    arr[2] = 5.0;
    // ...
```

At the very least, even if you're not going to use `CComSafeArray` it's worthwhile to deconstruct its source code in `<atlsafe.h>` giving you better insight on the what, when, why and how on `SAFEARRAY` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Passing SAFEARRAYs is not recommended.  It is recommended to place the SAFEARRAY into a VARIANT.  Further, the SAFEARRAY should hold VARIANT data.  This gives the best of all worlds and makes passing VARIANT SAFEARRAY of VARIANTs more useful to other languages.  E.g.  C++ to VB / C# (Note it is up to the caller to free/destroy the SAFEARRAY)

Building on the previous code

```
// A VARIANT holding a SAFEARRAY of VARIANTs
VARIANT vRet;

SAFEARRAYBOUND Bound;
Bound.lLbound = 0;
Bound.cElements = 10;

SAFEARRAY * psaData = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, &Bound);

VARIANT HUGEP * pData = NULL;
HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(psaData, (void HUGEP * FAR *)&pData);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    for (short i = 0; i < 10; ++i,++pData)
    {
        ::VariantInit(pData);
        pData->vt = VT_I2;
        pData->iVal = i;
    }

    SafeArrayUnaccessData(psaData);
}

vRet.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
vRet.parray = psaData;
```