# VBA array is longer than I expect

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple problem.  I have the following code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim vr() As String
    ReDim vr(1)
    vr(0) = 1
    For i = 0 To UBound(vr)
        Debug.Print (vr(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Even though I have set the length of the array to one, the array actually has two positions:

```
vr(0) = 1
vr(1) = ""
```

Why does it have two positions even though I have set the length to one?

Comment: As it has been said, you need to use Option Base 1 in order that excel starts arrays' at position 1 rather than 0 as default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I'd try the following.

`Redim vr(0 to 0)`

Do you have [`Option Base`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx) at the top of your module?  Is it `Option Base 0` or `Option Base 1`?

Regardless specifying both lower and upper bounds as per above example will insulate from whatever `Option Base` says at the top.

Comment: Don't need to ask about the base - the OP is setting `vr(0)`, so they **know** that there is a position 0.  I think they just don't expect there to be a position 1 despite setting that as the upper bound.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is thinking that a `ReDim` specifies the **number** of positions in an array, instead of the upper and lower bounds.  (So they probably think that `ReDim vr(2)` should do what we would write as `ReDim vr(-5 To -4)` but, of course, it doesn't.)

Comment: @YowE3K: I agree, like C++  `int foo[5]` gives elements 0 to 4  but not VBA.

Comment: Curious - does c++ allow a non-zero base?  i.e. can it do the equivalent of VBA's `ReDim vr(-5 To -4)` or does it always start from `0`?

Comment: @YowE3K: no, not unless one uses a SAFEARRAY which is what VBA uses under the hood.  Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730840/#3735438

Comment: Okay I understand.  Redim v(1) is not the same as int v[1] ? How doest it work then?

Comment: @fossekall:  I have edited answer to include a link to MSDN for Option Base.  All of the information is in the answer.