# C++ to C# char[]

Tags: visual-c++, interop

C# code:

```
class Hello{
    public void helloWorld(char[] chars){
        //do something
    }
}
```

C++ code to call C#:

```
MyCSDLL::Hello* hello;
//init hello, some calls are ok.

char* myCharPtr;
//init with message
 HRESULT result = hello->helloWorld(safeArray, (MyCSDLL::_MyRetVal) _retValPtr);
```

Adapting from [How to create and initialize SAFEARRAY of doubles in C++ to pass to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730840/how-to-create-and-initialize-safearray-of-doubles-in-c-to-pass-to-c-sharp)

```
void createSafeArray(SAFEARRAY** saData, char* charPtr)
{
    char* iterator = charPtr;
    SAFEARRAYBOUND  Bound;
    Bound.lLbound = 0;
    Bound.cElements = 10;

    *saData = SafeArrayCreate(VT_R8, 1, &Bound);

    char HUGEP *pdFreq;
    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(*saData, (void HUGEP* FAR*)&pdFreq);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        do {
            *pdFreq++ = *iterator;
        } while (*iterator++);

    }

}
```

How to call `hello->helloWorld()`? it is expecting `SAFEARRAY*`. The current code gives 80131538 error. How to fix it?

C++ Project is not CLR.

Comment: Yes.  Consider to [create a safe array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraycreate).  Maybe char[] was not a very good choice, it rarely is, hard to tell.

Comment: Please check the code for `createSafeArray()`. The method call is failing now.

Comment: It should fail, you created a double[] with VT_R8.  This should not be a char[] at all, it should be byte[].  Use VT_U1.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose the C# code is this:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class Hello
    {
        public void helloWorld(char[] chars)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can call it with this C/C++ code, for example:

```
#import "C:\mycode\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\classlibrary1.tlb" raw_interfaces_only

using namespace ClassLibrary1;

HRESULT CallHello(wchar_t* charPtr, int count)
{
  CComPtr<_Hello> p;
  HRESULT hr = p.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(Hello));
  if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;

  SAFEARRAY* psa = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UI2, 0, count);
  if (!psa)
    return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

  LPVOID pdata;
  hr = SafeArrayAccessData(psa, &pdata);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
  {
    CopyMemory(pdata, charPtr, count * 2); // count is the number of chars
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);
    hr = p->helloWorld(psa);
  }
  SafeArrayDestroy(psa);
  return hr;
}
```

.NET's `char` type is unicode, so the binary size is two bytes, the C equivalent is `wchar_t` (or unsigned short, etc...). So the safearray element type must match that, that's why I used `VT_UI2` (`VT_R8` that you used is Real of size 8 bytes, so it's equivalent to .NET's `double` type).

If you really want to use C's `char`, then you must do some kind of conversion to a 2-byte character.

Also, you can use the `SafeArrayCreateVector` function which directly allocates a 1-dimension safe array. Don't forget to call cleanup methods.